# get the selected items in a sharepoint list using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript

In my SharePoint 2013 list , i am trying to get the ids of selected items using javascript . I used below script in content editor web part :

[image]

by using this i am able to get the ids . but i have two problems:

1. the result i am getting is like - **1,1,0** or **1,2,0**  if i select items.
2. I need to get the collection of selected.
3. I need to select item by clicking on checkbox which is not working although i have put up input type as checkbox id.

Comment: That code works? I see quite a few issues with it

Answer (score 4):

Please mark Sam's answer as the correct one.

Note that on the current ListView page the global `ctx` is already available,
so a call to `get_current()` is not required

SP.ListOperations take the default `ctx` when none is specified.

```
var selected=SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
```

Gets you an Object array

```
var selectedStr = selected.map(function(item){ // loop all Objects
    return item.id;                            // return the ID
}).join(',');                                  // concatenate to one string 
console.log('selected IDs:',selectedStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code.

```
function clickMethod() {

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);

var mySeletedItems = '';

 var i;

 for (i in items)
 {
      mySeletedItems += '|' + items[i].id;
 }
alert (mySeletedItems);

}
```

Hope it will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the selected items from the list view, you can use the SP.ListOperation to get the selected items using Javascript. Refer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115429/get-list-id-and-selected-item-id)

Also, the below for more references.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407815(v=office.14).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409526(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Both code example answers are kinda wrong.

**Correct usage**

```
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems() // parameter won't do things
```

[image]

**What's wrong with the current answers**

-> [Samir Khimani](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209446/get-the-selected-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-using-javascript/209447#209447)

You can't provide a context since the function does not take parameters.
[image]

-> [Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209446/get-the-selected-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-using-javascript/209460#209460)

While it is true that the function uses a context, this context neither can be provided as parameter nor is a `SP.ClientContext`. It's actually the list context of the currently selected list and will also work with mutliple lists on the page.
[image]